# What is a Class Library in Java?

Tags: java

What is a Class library in Java?  Is it a collection of classes with in a package, or it is a package that has collection of classes?

I'm bit confused. ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a collection of classes, usually bundled up in a [jar file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)). All the classes *may* be in the same Java package, but they don't have to be. A class library in a jar file may also contain resources and meta-data that it needs (e.g. string translations, driver information for other frameworks etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, class libraries are just sets of classes in a package.

They could be stored in a folder but mostly they are distributed in JARs (Java ARchives), which are just zipped up class files.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaTM Archive (JAR) file format enables you to bundle multiple files into a single archive file. Typically a JAR file contains the class files and auxiliary resources associated with applets and applications.

You can get more information from [this link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/)